# pydがimportできない場合の対処法は？

Tags: python, python3, cython

インタプリタからfoo.pydをimportすると正常にできて，同じフォルダ内にあるabcde.pydをimportすると次のエラーがでます．

```
>>> import abcde
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: DLL load failed: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。
```

同じフォルダにあるのでパスは問題ないと思い`dumpbin /exports`すると次のように関数`PyInit_*`も存在するようです．

```
> dumpbin /exports abcde
 :
           1    0 00027CA0 PyInit_abcde
 :
```

このような状態のとき，他に何の問題があると考えられますでしょうか？また，どのようにして確認できますでしょうか？

教えて頂ければ幸いです．ただし，どちらもC++からcythonで作成したpydで，foo.pydは自前の簡単なコードから作成したもので，もう一方はabcde.pydは他のライブラリをコンパイルしたものです（すみません具体的には明かせません）．

Answer (score 1):

> もう一方はabcde.pydは他のライブラリをコンパイルしたものです（すみません具体的には明かせません）．

その「他のライブラリ」とやらがDLLで、[適切な場所にないために](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/7d83bc18.aspx)ロードに失敗しているのではないですか?

「abcde.pyd」が単に見つからないのであれば、ImportErrorではなく、ModuleNotFoundErrorになると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます．なるほど，つまりabcde.pydは見つかってもそこから呼び出される別のDLLへのpathが通っていない可能性があるということですね．他のDLLがロードできない場合は，DLLの名前がエラーメッセージに表示されるものばかり思っていました．

上の理解が正しければですが，そのロードできないDLLが何なのか確認するすべはございますでしょうか？

Comment: 問題となっているDLLが何なのかは調べられないと思いますが、とりあえず「dumpbin /dependents」で何のDLLが必要かは調べられるので、一つ一つ確認してはいかがですか。

Comment: http://yohshiy.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-65.html

Comment: まだ解決しておらず，dumpbin /dependentsをしたところ

    opencv_world342.dll
    python36.dll
    MSVCP140.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    VCRUNTIME140.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll

となり何れもPATH環境変数でパスは通っているのですが，

    > from ctypes import *
    > cdll.LoadLibrary("xxxx.dll")

でロードできるか確認したところopencv_world342.dllだけ「OSError: [WinError 126] 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。」となりました．これが原因なのかとも思うですが，原因も確認方法が正しいのかも分からない状態です．

Comment: 解決しました．DLLが呼び出す別のDLLのパスが通っていなかったようです．ctypes.util.find_library()を使ってしらみつぶしにチェックしたら発見できました．

Comment: 解決しましたか。良かったです。